# Subscribe from a python server to an aws-iot topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot, aws-iot-greengrass

I basically need to send a command to a device from a python server and the device will publish the reply to a topic and I need to catch the reply server side.
To publish from the server to the device I'm using the boto3 iot-data module. But how can I subscribe to another topic to get the reply from the device? It seems there is no way by using the aws python libraries. Do I need to use a genetic MQTT client like paho?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, the AWS SDK for Python does not provide a method for subscribing to a MQTT topic. You can either use the [AWS Python IoT SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2), or a generic MQTT client like Paho.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So I need to create a certificate (with the associated key) from the aws iot dashboard and using it into the MQTT library. Doesn't the certificate need to be attached to a thing or can be a generic certificate?